# Not able to widen the margins in CSS, code copied from net and trying to modify it as per requirement

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project for my degree course. I copied the code for split screen from net and now trying to modify the page as per the project requirements.
i am stuck with modifying CSS class for changing the margin settings.

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #333;
}

.splitlayout {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Intro sides */

.side {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.open-left .side,
.open-right .side {
  cursor: default;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 499;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.side-left .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.side-right .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.side-left {
  left: 0;
  background: #47a3da;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 1px solid #47a3da;
  /* avoid gap */
}

.side-right {
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #47a3da;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  /* avoid gap */
}


/* Intro content, profile image and name, back button */

.intro-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.profile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #47a3da;
}

.profile img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.intro-content h1>span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.intro-content h1>span:first-child {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.intro-content h1>span:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.intro-content h1>span:nth-child(2):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
}

.side-right .intro-content h1>span:nth-child(2):before {
  background: #47a3da;
}

.back {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2.6em;
  z-index: 500;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #47a3da;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 44px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.mobile-layout .back {
  /* fixed positioning will make this not clickable after scrolling on some mobile devices */
  position: absolute;
}

.back-left {
  left: 12.5%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.back-right {
  right: 12.5%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.open-right .back-left,
.open-left .back-right {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.back:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}


/* Pages */

.page {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.page-right {
  left: 25%;
  outline: 5px solid #ecf0f1;
  /* avoid rounding gaps */
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #97a8b2;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.splitlayout.open-right {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

.page-left {
  left: 0;
  outline: 5px solid #34495e;
  /* avoid rounding gaps */
  background: #34495e;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.splitlayout.open-left {
  background: #34495e;
}


/* Inner page content */

.page-inner {
  padding: 2em;
}

.page-inner section {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.page-inner h2 {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.4em;
}

.page-inner p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}


/* All transitions */

.side,
.page {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.overlay {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s, visibility 0.1s 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s, visibility 0.1s 0.6s;
}

.intro-content {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, top 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, top 0.6s;
}

.intro-content h1,
.back {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}


/* Open and close */


/* We need to set the position and overflow for the respective page scroll */

.reset-layout .page,
.splitlayout.open-right .page-left,
.splitlayout.open-left .page-right,
.splitlayout.close-right .page-left,
.splitlayout.close-left .page-right {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.splitlayout.open-right .page-right,
.splitlayout.open-left .page-left {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.open-right .side-left .overlay,
.open-left .side-right .overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}


/* Right side open */

.open-right .side-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-60%);
  transform: translateX(-60%);
}

.open-right .side-right {
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
  transform: translateX(-150%);
}

.close-right .side-right {
  z-index: 200;
}

.open-right .side-right .intro-content {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0%) scale(0.6);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0%) scale(0.6);
}

.open-right .page-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}


/* Left side open */

.open-left .side-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(60%);
  transform: translateX(60%);
}

.open-left .side-left {
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(150%);
  transform: translateX(150%);
}

.close-left .side-left {
  z-index: 200;
}

.open-left .side-left .intro-content {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-100%) scale(0.6);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-100%) scale(0.6);
}

.open-left .codropsheader {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.1s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.open-left .page-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}


/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 83em) {
  .intro-content {
    font-size: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
  body {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 49.4375em) {
  .open-right .side-right {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-175%);
    transform: translateX(-175%);
  }
  .open-right .side-left {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  .open-left .side-right {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  .open-left .side-left {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(175%);
    transform: translateX(175%);
  }
  .page {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .page-right {
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 15%;
  }
  .page-left {
    padding-right: 15%;
  }
  .intro-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .open-right .side-right .intro-content {
    top: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px) translateX(-12.5%) scale(0.5);
    transform: translateY(-150px) translateX(-12.5%) scale(0.5);
  }
  .open-left .side-left .intro-content {
    top: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px) translateX(-87.5%) scale(0.5);
    transform: translateY(-150px) translateX(-87.5%) scale(0.5);
  }
  .open-right .intro-content h1,
  .open-left .intro-content h1 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .back-left {
    left: 6.25%;
  }
  .back-right {
    right: 6.25%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 42.5em) {
  body {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
  .intro-content {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 41.125em) {
  .intro-content {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%) translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-25%) translateX(-50%);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 39.375em) {
  .intro-content .profile {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  body {
    font-size: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
  <title>Admin Console</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component2.css" />
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css" /-->
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="side side-left">
      <header class="codropsheader clearfix">
        <span>
                  <img height=100px width=90px src="img/profile2.jpg" alt="profile2" align="left">
                </span>
        <h1>College Of Telecommunication</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="side side-right">
        <header class="codropsheader clearfix">
          <span>
                      <img height=100px src="img/profile1.jpg" alt="profile2" align="right">
                      </span>
          <h1>Engineering,</h1>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I'm trying to add a text after  it is not taking full width of the split screen. any help appreciated

Comment: When I add text in the left or right column it is full-width, so I don't know where you are adding text. Check out this code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egQRZW